# Xamarin form : What package to use similar to IdentityModel

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, openid, portable-class-library

I have problem with installing identity model from nuget. It doesn't support the Xamarin form PCL project. I tried to use 1.13.1 version but looks like missing DiscoveryClient class and not sure it work as the same as latest version.

Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: IdentityModel2 (.NetStandard-based) : https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2

Comment: Yes that is the one I tried to install the project but I have error adding to my PCL project. Could not install package 'IdentityModel 2.16.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78'

Comment: .NetStandard is the future, Profile-based PCLs are dying a quick death.

Comment: I see so if I have an application using Profile-based.  Can it be switch to .net standard easily.

Comment: Easily is a relative term, if all the 3rd-party libs you are using support .NetStd, then yes, if not, you have to deal with fallbacks and if you are using Xamarin.Forms you need to be using the latest version, Xamarin has docs:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/under-the-hood/net-standard/ and blog posts (just do a "netstandard" search): http://blog.xamarin.com/

Comment: In the Build -> General under Target Framework, I can only see netstandard1.5 even though I install the .NetCore 2.0 to my Mac.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio for Mac do you have installed?

Comment: I think i've got it. I created the multplatform .net library, copied the App.xaml and Other useful files to the new library project and remove the PCL project.